# How to remove outer object and set key to inner object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have object structure like this:

```
{ 'xxx@gmail.com': 

   {
     contactNo0: { contact: [Object] },
     contactNo1: { contact: [Object] },
     contactNo2: { contact: [Object] },
     contactNo3: { contact: [Object] } 
   }
}
```

I don't have a key for outer object and I don't need one. I just want to remove the outer object.

I have created the above object this way:

```
var contactObj = {};
for(var i=0; i<retrievedContactsArr.length; i++){
    contactObj['contactNo'+i] = retrievedContactsArr[i];
}
var key = {};
key[username] = (contactObj);
console.log('printing key with object...' , key);
```

Desired output:

```
'xxx@gmail.com': {
 contactNo0: { contact: [Object] },
 contactNo1: { contact: [Object] },
 contactNo2: { contact: [Object] },
 contactNo3: { contact: [Object] } 
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Your desired output looks exactly like your actual input

Comment: @thefourtheye I have these extra `{ }` enclosing the inner object. It doesn't matter?

Comment: accessing `key.username` or `key.contactNo0` is giving undefined

Comment: Without the "extra" curly braces it will throw an error

Comment: I guess I need to access it this way `key[username]` as username is dynamic value

Comment: @YerkoPalma Is there a better way of writing the code I have written above?

Comment: I would remove the `()` in the `key[username]` asignation, also you are right about accesing the object property with square brackets instead of the dot notacion, because of the special chars in the property name. And the problem with your _desired output_ is basically that is a syntactic error in javascript